# Maven dependency plugin - include files and folders

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project with a structure:

```
Project
|---lib
|   |---<files and folders I want to include>
|
|---src
|   |---<regular files and folders>
|
|---pom.xml
```

In my pom.xml I have:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies-third-party</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/dist/lib/third-party</outputDirectory>
                    <excludeGroupIds>...</excludeGroupIds>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And it copies all my maven dependencies to `target/dist/lib/third-party` directory. How can I also include **all** files/folders from **lib** (see in structure above) folder to that location?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Looks like a distribution archive? If yes than maven-dependency-plugin is the wrong way...

Comment: what kind of the files that are stored in lib/? is it jar or another binary artifact or is it a source code?

Comment: those are some configuration files and property files (required by some other third-party jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these files are configuration and properties files i would classify them as resources and would use the [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) to include them.

```
<resources>
   <!-- The resources in the lib folder -->
   <resource>
      <directory>lib</directory>
      <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/dist/lib/third-party</targetPath>

      <!-- add this if you want to define parameters in these resources -->
      <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>

   <!-- We need to redeclare the project resources again -->
   <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

It answers exactly your question